# What exactly happens in this scene with Gamora and Thanos?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In the movie *Avengers: Infinity War*, there is a scene on *Knowhere* where *Gamora* tries and manages to kill *Thanos* and before he asks,

> Why did you do this, my child?

while *Gamora* keeps crying.

But then he suddenly resurrects and captures *Gamora*.

What exactly happened in this scene?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## It's an illusion

Thanos created an illusion (or false reality) with the Reality Stone to test Gamora.

He says...

> "Reality can be whatever I want."

---

It's unlikely that Thanos could even be hurt by Gamora with a puny weapon like a knife.

Recall, it takes all of Iron Man's power to get one drop of blood from Thanos and even a strike by Thor using Stormbreaker *to the heart* didn't kill him.

Comment: "even a strike by Thor using Stormbreaker to the heart didn't kill him" - I'd tack an "instantly" onto that as a qualifier.  He seemed pretty mortally wounded, and did more-or-less say that a headshot would have killed him.  My assumption was that part of his wish on the infinity stones was to heal/save himself, and that otherwise he would have died from the wound.  Although, who's to say that Thanos's heart is in his chest; or that he even has one for that matter?  He's some kind of alien, after all.

Comment: @aroth a titan to be specific.

Comment: To me that knife seemed to be kinda special. From the dialogues I had thought that the substance in that knife is some kind of venom that is able to actually kill Thanos (which is the reason Gamora actually used it)

Comment: I can't find anything in the transcript mentioning the knife at all.

Comment: @aroth: Death has declared Thanos incapable of entering her domain making him immortal. However, a blow to the head might have given the Avengers time to disarm Thanos.

Comment: @Murch Death is in the comics which are not under discussion here.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I was merely suggesting that it's unclear whether Thanos can actually die in MCU.

Comment: Indications are that he can if *Thor had gone for the head*.